# Whole url as react router param

Tags: react-router

I need to pass url as is as react router parameter :) Please help to understand how to achieve this. Don't tell its impossible because it is possible :) I just need to know how...

For example: I have param value: love/story/of/my/life/ and my end point is like this:

http://example.com/story-name/

So then when I visit this url:
http://example.com/story-name/love/story/of/my/life/

I want to receive: love/story/of/my/life/ as a parameter. Encoding is not an option, I need to keep my initial url and its beauty.

Why i need this because this url comes from another system which has url as configurable parameter, so if i break it into several parameters, it will not work after user changes configuration, but I need it to always receive a whole url as a parameter while keeping old url look as it was.

Comment: by they way i cannot get rid only of slashes (/), but other special symbols like question marks quotes etc i can escape.

Answer (score 0):

So far what comes to mind mind is to create same processor method for router from 1 to 20 params and glue them all together. This is not perfect but does the job, does anyone have more elegant solutions?